# Any way to get string out of a string that has no definite length?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this problem in SQL Server that I'm trying to figure out. I have this string saved in the database which has the download location and download date of a file so it can have as much length, sample here.

```
downloadedFile = c:/Programs and Features/Public/MyFiles/Myfile Mar 23 12:55 PM
```

or it can be like this:

```
downloadedFile = C:/Programs and Feature/Public/MyFiles/FileTypes/MOV/MyFile Mar 23 1:25 PM
```

Can I get the full DATETIME even if it changes format? First example above was from MM DD HH:MM format Second was MM DD H:MM format, as you can see, hour came from two digits to one, screwing up my chance of using substring. This string is in the middle of a string, so if, even one character adds to the result set, a problem might occur parsing it to datetime. Any ideas?

Comment: here date part always comes after "Myfile "?

Comment: Yes. It always comes after the file so I can get the date and time, problem is, length varies, so substring, which needs me to count how many characters from the startpoint is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use  [CHARINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) Function

```
declare @downloadedFile varchar(500);
set @downloadedFile = 
     'c:/Programs and Features/Public/MyFiles/Myfile Mar 23 12:55 PM'

select substring(@downloadedFile,
                 CHARINDEX('Myfile ',@downloadedFile)+7,LEN(@downloadedFile))
```

Result:

```
Mar 23 12:55 PM
```

.

```
set @downloadedFile = 
 'C:/Programs and Feature/Public/MyFiles/FileTypes/MOV/MyFile Mar 23 1:25 PM';

select substring(@downloadedFile,
        CHARINDEX('Myfile ',@downloadedFile)+7,LEN(@downloadedFile))
```

result:

```
Mar 23 1:25 PM
```

Comment: I did something like this, and just set length of the expression on the next charindex. This helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an analog function to split string.
use the "space" as delimiter. And the last 4 indices of the array is your date/time.

Maybe this could help you

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4126a010-6885-4eb0-b79c-c798c90edb85